# Reference web projects from other web projects in solution

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, port

I am working in Visual Studio 2013/2015. I have three web projects in my solution. I want these web projects to be able to make calls to each other, which means that they need to know at what port they are hosted on during development.

I am hosting in IIS Express, which by default means that they get auto-assigned ports. This is good because if a port is unavailable, another port will be used. Since the port is determined at runtime I cannot have a configuration file in each projects which says where the other projects are hosted.

Other than manually assigning ports, is it possible to somehow reference these other web projects from one web project and then make calls where the used port is substituted?

Comment: Is that really what you want to do, or would it be better to set up your development environment in the same way that you will deploy these sites ? Is full IIS available? What sort of calls are we talking about?

Comment: I'm sure there are ways to do so, but one way or another you'll introduce code that's only relevant during development, and you don't want that. Just fix the port numbers and put the URLs in your web.config; in production your ports won't change either.

Comment: @StephenKennedy Full IIS is available, but this requires running VS as admin which is a hassle when visual studio restarts itself without elevated privileges, and projects doesn't load. We have many different products and we need to keep the dev environments of these products as contained as possible - CI and CD to multiple staging sites will take care of testing the application in a 'similar to prod' enviroment. The calls we are talking about are simply ordinary gets / posts / redirects. They are sister sites where we split the domain into two sites for maintainability.

Comment: @CodeCaster Even if we fix the port numbers, I believe IIS Express auto-assigns anyway if port is unavailable, perhaps due to a rogue instance of IIS Express still running. Ideally, we wouldn't need any / much code, just a way for VS to inject the IIS Express address into the running application, and we either use the pre-configured URL (for prod) or the runtime-determined URL for dev.

Comment: I had to go remind myself that using IIS requires VS to run with elevated priveledges and indeed I have "run as administrator" ticked. Been using IIS for debugging and not either of the issues you mention in 7+ years... I work on a white label site which renders differently depending on url. All relevant data, including domain names, is stored in a resellers db table. On dev box I put fake domain names into the table, bind IIS to those, and add them to my Windows hosts file. It takes some setting up but works a treat and aside from the db change, I know that dev enviroment mostly == deployment